# Python: how to capture output to a text file? (only 25 of 530 lines captured now)

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I've done a fair amount of lurking on SO and a fair amount of searching and reading, but I must also confess to being a relative noob at programming in general. I am trying to learn as I go, and so I have been playing with Python's NLTK. In the script below, I can get everything to work, except it only writes what would be the first screen of a multi-screen output, at least that's how I am thinking about it.

Here's the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import nltk

# First we have to open and read the file:

thefile = open('all_no_id.txt')
raw = thefile.read()

# Second we have to process it with nltk functions to do what we want

tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(tokens)

# Now we can actually do stuff with it:

concord = text.concordance("cultural")

# Now to save this to a file

fileconcord = open('ccord-cultural.txt', 'w')
fileconcord.writelines(concord)
fileconcord.close()
```

And here's the beginning of the output file:

```
Building index...
Displaying 25 of 530 matches:
y .   The Baobab Tree : Stories of Cultural Continuity The continuity evident 
 regardless of ethnicity , and the cultural legacy of Africa as well . This Af
```

What am I missing here to get the entire 530 matches written to the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`text.concordance(self, word, width=79, lines=25)` seem to have other parameters  as per [manual](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.text-pysrc.html#Text.concordance).

I see no way to extract the size of concordance index, however, the [concordance printing code](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.text-pysrc.html#ConcordanceIndex.print_concordance) seem to have this part: `lines = min(lines, len(offsets))`, therefore you can simply pass `sys.maxint` as a last argument:

```
concord = text.concordance("cultural", 75, sys.maxint)
```

**Added:**

Looking at you original code now, I can't see a way it could work before. `text.concordance` does not return anything, but outputs everything to `stdout` using `print`. Therefore, the easy option would be redirection stdout to you file, like this:

```
import sys

....

# Open the file
fileconcord = open('ccord-cultural.txt', 'w')
# Save old stdout stream
tmpout = sys.stdout
# Redirect all "print" calls to that file
sys.stdout = fileconcord
# Init the method
text.concordance("cultural", 200, sys.maxint)
# Close file
fileconcord.close()
# Reset stdout in case you need something else to print
sys.stdout = tmpout
```

Another option would be to use the respective classes directly and omit the Text wrapper. Just copy bits from [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.text-pysrc.html#Text.concordance) and combine them with bits from [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.text-pysrc.html#ConcordanceIndex.print_concordance) and you are done.

Comment: Interesting. When I added the additional parameters I get a blank file and the following response: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concordance.py", line 23, in <module>
    fileconcord.writelines(concord)
TypeError: writelines() requires an iterable argument` (Sorry for things being jammed together -- I can't find a way to enter more than one return in this comment space.)

Comment: An additional discovery: the second parameter allows me to set the amount of context: when I changed it to 250 I got a total of 250 bytes per line. Sweet!

Comment: @JohnLaudun Weird, now I don't get how your original code worked at all, looking at nltk sources - it clearly shouldnt. `text.concordance` does not return anything, it prints everything using `print`. Therefore you could redirect the output of stdout I guess. See the addition to my post for details.

Comment: I swapped your code added above for mine and ... it works. I get all 530 lines of code. This does not answer your question above -- about why this works at all, but it works for now, which is great. My thanks to you and Levon for all your help.

Comment: Now I am off to find a way to have the script ask for the term to be concordanced and then use it to name the results file: e.g. `What term would you like to see?` // $term (return) --> cord-$term.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

I found this [write text.concordance output to a file Options](https://groups.google.com/group/nltk-users/browse_thread/thread/2b4dbb4ab93e282a?fwc=1&pli=1)
 from the ntlk usergroup. It's from 2010, and states:

> Documentation for the Text class says: "is intended to support 
>   initial exploration of texts (via the interactive console). ... If you
>   wish to write a program which makes use of these analyses, then you 
>   should bypass the Text class, and use the appropriate analysis 
>   function or class directly instead."

If nothing has changed in the package since then, this may be the source of your problem.

--- previously ---

I don't see a problem with writing to the file using [writelines()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=writelines#file.writelines):

> file.writelines(sequence)
>
> Write a sequence of strings to the file. The sequence can be any
>   iterable object producing strings, typically a list of strings. There
>   is no return value. (The name is intended to match readlines();
>   *writelines() does not add line separators*.)

Note the italicized part, did you examine the output file in different editors? Perhaps the data is there, but not being rendered correctly due to missing end of line seperators?

Are you sure this part is generating the data you want to output?

```
 concord = text.concordance("cultural")
```

I'm not familiar with `nltk`, so I'm just asking as part of eliminating possible sources for the problem.

Comment: Sorry to reveal the very early state of my understanding, but do you have any suggestions on how to use `writelines` here? I did, in fact try this in an earlier version of the script and had no luck.

Comment: Also, I had not encountered that series of discussions, so, first, thank you. Clearly I am going to have to wrap my head around the Text class.

Comment: @JohnLaudun I think you are using `writelines` correctly. It appears from the previous discussion on the ntlk userlist that you can't simply print out the data. I'm unfortunately not familiar with `ntlk` to make any suggestions. Perhaps the ntlk has changed since then? I'd have to there would be a way to dump the data into a file.

Comment: I wish the system enabled me to give you credit, too, for all your help. Many, many thanks.