# How to save NLTK concordance results in a list?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I'm using the NLTK to find word in a text. I need to save result of concordance function into a list. The question is already asked  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135369/get-all-results-frm-nltk-concordance)
but i cannot see the changes. I try to find the type of returnde value of the function by :

```
type(text.concordance('myword'))
```

the result was :

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: how to capture output to a text file? (only 25 of 530 lines captured now)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044072/python-how-to-capture-output-to-a-text-file-only-25-of-530-lines-captured-now)

Comment: i aready saw this post, but i  prefer to avoid passing by file.

Comment: Concordances can only be captured through the stdout, there's no way to save the concordance yet but there's a PR to do so: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspecting the source of [`ConcordanceIndex`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html#ConcordanceIndex), we can see that results are printed to stdout. If [redirecting stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675744/3423035) is not an option, you have to reimplement the `ConcordanceIndex.print_concordance` such that it returns the results rather than printing it to stdout.

**Code:**

```
def concordance(ci, word, width=75, lines=25):
    """
    Rewrite of nltk.text.ConcordanceIndex.print_concordance that returns results
    instead of printing them. 

    See:
    http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.ConcordanceIndex.print_concordance
    """
    half_width = (width - len(word) - 2) // 2
    context = width // 4 # approx number of words of context

    results = []
    offsets = ci.offsets(word)
    if offsets:
        lines = min(lines, len(offsets))
        for i in offsets:
            if lines <= 0:
                break
            left = (' ' * half_width +
                    ' '.join(ci._tokens[i-context:i]))
            right = ' '.join(ci._tokens[i+1:i+context])
            left = left[-half_width:]
            right = right[:half_width]
            results.append('%s %s %s' % (left, ci._tokens[i], right))
            lines -= 1

    return results
```

**Usage:**

```
from nltk.book import text1
from  nltk.text import ConcordanceIndex

ci = ConcordanceIndex(text1.tokens)
results = concordance(ci, 'circumstances')

print(type(results))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Is this feature something that people like to see in NLTK? If so, give some love to https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1333 and we'll see how far/fast we can push this into proper nltk function =)

Comment: There is now a function that returns a list. See my answer

Answer (score 3):

The Text class [now has](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2196) a `concordance_list` function. For example:

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
from nltk.text import Text

corpus = gutenberg.words('melville-moby_dick.txt')
text = Text(corpus)
con_list = text.concordance_list("monstrous")
```

Answer (score 0):

To use text concordance, you need to instantiate a NLTK `Text()` object and then use `concordance()` method on that object :

```
import nltk.corpus  
from nltk.text import Text  
moby = Text(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words('melville-moby_dick.txt'))
```

Here we instantiate a Text object on the text file `melville-moby_dick.txt` and then we are able to use the method :

```
moby.concordance("monster")
```

If you have a NonType here, it seeems to be because you did not created any `Text` object and so your variable `text` is `None`.

Comment: I did not write complete code, but text  was an  NLTK Text object.  I post this line of code to check the return type of the concordance method